# Failed to find provider info for ContentProvider

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-contentprovider

I have seen a few similar posts to this, but i already have had the `ContentProvider` registered in my `AndroidManifest`.

I have a `ContentProvider` called `MyContentProvider`.

And `MyContentProvider` is located in a library project called `MyProject`. With package location `personal.mobile.abc.angry.tiger.MyContentProvider`.

---

My `AndroidManifest` for this project looks like this (left out info that is not related):

```
<application
    android:label=...
    android:icon=...
    android:theme=...>
    <provider
        android:name="personal.mobile.abc.angry.tiger.MyContentProvider"
        android:authorities="personal.mobile.abc.angry.tiger">
    </provider>
</application>
```

---

Lint keeps saying this:

```
The <provider> personal.mobile.abc.angry.tiger.MyContentProvider is not registered in the manifest.
```

---

And Logcat says this when attempting to run the application that includes the library that contains the `ContentProvider`:

```
Failed to find provider info for personal.mobile.abc.angry.tiger
```

---

What am i doing wrong? What is the issue?

If you need any further information, please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: In which projects(s) do you have that `<provider>` element? The library? The app? Both?

Comment: The `<provider>` element is in the project that contains the `ContentProvider`. The library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `<provider>` element needs to be in the application, as it is the one with the `ContentProvider`. The fact that the Java class implementing that `ContentProvider` happens to be in an Android library project does not change the fact that the hosting app is the one responsible for that provider.

Eventually -- perhaps as soon as ADT 21 -- your `<provider>` element in the library project can be automatically added to your application project. Right now, AFAIK, that process is manual.

Comment: Wow. I was thinking you only needed it in the library. Feel like i have done it before where it was only in the library. Thanks for the help.